# font-size css3 transition is not smooth in chrome

Tags: html, css

I've created a very simple animation for a `h1` tag, the animation uses `css3` `font-size` transition.

http://jsbin.com/oPIQoyoT/1/edit

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    width:500px;
    height: 500px;
    font-size: 3em;
    transition: font-size 0.5s ease-in;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
h1:hover {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

It appears to be very smooth in firefox, chrome doesn't render it properly.

I've tried setting the position to absolute, defining width, height but none of this did really help.

How can I make it as smooth in Chrome as in Firefox? Can you please provide a jsbin example?

Comment: Can you define smooth? It appears to run fine in mine but just checking what your definition of smooth is

Comment: @Marriott81 As I can see, the transition in FF seems to have more fps than in CH. E.g. it's like in CH the animation was with 12 fps and in FF was 24 fps.

Answer (score -1):

You can Use

```
text-shadow: 0.0em 0.0em 0.07em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

see this [link](http://kazymjir.com/blog/chrome-font-smoothing-antialiasing-fix/) &
[link2](http://www.dev-metal.com/fix-ugly-font-rendering-google-chrome/)